# Gulp – пересборка только изменённых файлов

Tags: gulp

```
точки входа
bundle.js
entry-1.js
entry-2.js
entry-3.js

bundle.css
entry-1.css
entry-2.css
entry-3.css

исходники в папках
sourses/js
  - main.js через import включает остальное из папки
  - nav.js
  - test.js
sourses/css
  - main.scss через import включает остальное из папки
  - nav.scss
  - test.scss
```

наблюдение(watch) за папкой sourses и перекомпиляция для каждой точки входа

```
gulp.watch('sources/**/*.js', gulp.series(entryname);
```

но не выходит последний пункт - перекомпилируются все точки входа, вместо одной, в которой код поменялся

как можно отследить какие файлы были изменены, включая импортированые?

Comment: Возможно я не так понял вопрос но может быть так
 
 gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
 gulp.watch([path.watch.css], cssWatch);
const build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(html, css, js, images, fonts));

Comment: @MaxWatson поняли верно, но так не выйдет, исходиники общие для всего сайта и лежат в папке sources, то есть path.watch.css это не одна папка в sources а несколько десятков, согласно логической структуре проекта(navigation, widgets etc) в общем собрать все пути ко всем папкам для каждого раздела сайта(для каждой entrypoint) не выйдет

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer).